# WordPress Template: Unable to Add Comment Replies in Custom Theme

Tags: php, wordpress, comments

I'm creating a WordPress template, and I'm having an issue with the commenting system, specifically with adding replies to comments. In other themes, when you click "reply," you can directly respond to a specific comment, and the replied comment has a different depth. In the code I've created, it only allows adding new comments. However, if I reply to comments in the admin panel or in a different theme, everything works fine.

Here's what my **comments.php** code looks like:

```
<?php
if (!empty($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']) && 'comments.php' == basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']))
    die('Nie możesz bezpośrednio uruchomić tego pliku.');

if (post_password_required()) {
    echo 'Post jest chroniony hasłem. Wprowadź hasło aby zobaczyć komentarze.';
    return;
}
?>

<div class="comments">

        <?php if(!comments_open()) : ?>
        
        <?php else: ?>
        
                        <header>
                            <h2>Komentarze</h2>
                            <h3>Co myślą inni?</h3>
                        </header>

                        <div class="comments-list">
                        
                        <?php if(have_comments()) : ?>
                        
                            <?php
                                wp_list_comments(array(
                                    'callback' => 'lovetoeat_comment_theme',
                                    'style' => 'div',
                                    'avatar_size' => 69
                                ));
                            ?>
                        
                            
                        <?php else : ?>
                        
                            <p class="no-comments">Ten wpis nie posiada jeszcze żadnych komentrzy.</p>
                            
                        <?php endif; ?>
                        
                        </div>
                         <?php if (get_comment_pages_count() > 1 && get_option('page_comments') ) : ?>
                        <div class="comments-navi">
                                <div class="prev"><?php previous_comment_link('Starsze komentarze'); ?></div>
                                <div class="next"><?php next_comment_link('Nowsze komentarze'); ?></div>
                        </div>
                        <?php endif; ?>

                        <div id="respond">

                            <header>
                                <h2>
                                    <?php comment_form_title('Dodaj komentarz', 'Odpowiedź dla %s'); ?>
                                    <?php cancel_comment_reply_link('Kliknij tutaj, aby anulować odpowiadanie.'); ?>
                                </h2>
                                <h3>Masz jakiś pomysł?</h3>
                            </header>
                            
                        <?php if(get_option('comment_registration') && !is_user_logged_in()) : ?>
                        
                            <p>Musisz się <a href="<?php echo wp_login_url(get_permalink()); ?>">zalogować</a></p>
                            
                        <?php else : ?>

                            <form id="commentform" method="post" action="<?php echo get_option('siteurl'); ?>/wp-comments-post.php">
                            
                            <?php if(is_user_logged_in()) : ?>
                            
                                <p>Zalogowany jako: <a href="<?php echo get_option('siteurl'); ?>/wp-admin/profile.php"><?php echo $user_identity ?></a>. <a href="<?php echo wp_logout_url(get_permalink()); ?>">Wyjoguj się</a></p>
                            
                            <?php else : ?>
                            
                                <input type="text" name="author" placeholder="Imię i nazwisko">
                                <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Adres e-mail">
                                
                            <?php endif; ?>

                                <textarea name="comment" placeholder="Treść komentarza"></textarea>
                                
                                <?php comment_id_fields(); ?>

                                <button>Wyślij</button>
                                <?php do_action('comment_form', $post->ID); ?>
                                
                            </form>

                        <?php endif; ?>
                        </div>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    </div>
```

And here's the method in **functions.php**:

```
function lovetoeat_comment_theme($comment, $args, $depth) {
    $GLOBALS['comment'] = $comment;
    
    $tag = $args['style'];
?>

    <<?php echo $tag ?> <?php comment_class(empty($args['has_children']) ? '' : 'parent') ?> id="li-comment-<?php comment_ID() ?>">
        <div id="div-comment-<?php comment_ID(); ?>" class="inner">
            <?php echo get_avatar($comment, 69); ?>               
            <h4>
            <?php echo get_comment_author_link(); ?>
            <?php echo 'w dniu ' . get_comment_date() . 'o' . get_comment_time() ?>
            <?php comment_reply_link(array_merge($args, array('depth' => $depth, 'max_depth' => $args['max_depth']))) ?>
            </h4>
                <?php comment_text(); ?>
                
                <?php if($comment->comment_approved == '0') : ?>
                    <div class="comment-awaiting-moderation">Twój komentarz oczekuje na moderację!</div>
                <?php endif; ?>
        </div>
<?php
}
```